# the maxima of given function

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

What's the maxima of $$2^{\sin(x)}+2^{\cos(x)}$$ I found max by taking logs and then differentiating and equating to $0$ at $x=45°$ so the answer is $2^{\frac{\sqrt{2}+1}{\sqrt{2}}}$ am I right or I am missing something}

Comment: For one thing, you are missing any proof that you found the result by anything other than chance...

Comment: No I found it with derivative

Comment: According to wolframalpha, you are right. Obviously, the maximum is met for infinitely many values of $x$, not only $x=\dfrac\pi4$.

Comment: But my class answer sheets say its wrong

Comment: No sin,cos are periodic are $2Π$ thus I took that value

Comment: After edit: if by "taking logs" you mean that you used the well-known **wrong** identity $$\log_2\left(2^{\sin x}+2^{\cos x}\right)=\sin x+\cos x$$ then yes, you are wrong.

Comment: Ofcourse not that way

Comment: It is not difficult to figure out that for _any_ differentiable function $f$, the compound function $f(\sin(x)) + f(\cos(x))$ has a local extremum at $x = 45^\circ$ by using the chain rule and $\sin 45^\circ = \cos 45^\circ$.

Comment: The other maxima  are $ \pi/4 + 2 k \pi $

Answer (score 4):

This is the same as maximizing $f(x,y) = 2^x + 2^y$ subject to the constraint $g(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 = 1$.

Using Lagrange multipliers, we look for points where $g(x,y) = 1$ and $\nabla f(x,y) = ((\log 2)2^x,(\log 2)2^y)$ and $\nabla g(x,y) = (2x,2y)$ are linearly dependent. This is equivalent to $x2^{-x} = y2^{-y}$. But since the function $h(t) = t2^{-t}$ is strictly increasing on $[-1,1]$, the only solution on the unit circle is to take $x = y$, hence $x,y = \pm 1/\sqrt{2}$. A minus sign yields a minimum. The maximum is obtained using a plus sign and agrees with your answer.