# $P = 2^{|sinx|} + 2^{|cosx|}.$ Find $P_{max}$ and $P_{min}$.

Tags: calculus

> $P = 2^{|sinx|} + 2^{|cosx|}.$ Find $P_{max}$ and $P_{min}$.

Let $t = |sinx| \in [0, 1].$ We have that $P(t) = 2^t + 2^\sqrt{1 - t^2}.$

$P'(t) = 0 \iff t = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$

$P'(t) > 0$ for $t \in [0, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$ and $P'(t) < 0$ for $t \in (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}, 1].$ Also, $P(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) = 2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + 1}$ and $P(0) = P(1) = 3.$

Thus, $P_{max} = 2^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + 1}$ and $P_{min} = 3$

---

However, the above solution was my second attempt. Initially, I was using AM-GM and got to this point:

Let $\theta$ be such that $\sin\theta = |sinx|$ and $cos\theta = |cosx| \implies \theta \in [0, \frac\pi2] \implies \theta + \frac\pi4 \in [\frac\pi4, \frac{3\pi}{4}]$

$$P = 2^{|sinx|} + 2^{|cosx|} \geq 2\sqrt{2^{|sinx| + |cosx|}} \geq 2\sqrt{2^{\sqrt2sin(\theta + \frac\pi4)}} \geq 2\sqrt{2}$$

This seems to suggest that $P_{min} = 2\sqrt{2},$ which is incorrect. But I can't find what was wrong. Please advise.

Thank you!

Comment: Even though you found a lower bound, it doesn't implie that $P$ "reaches" that value. For example, I could show that $P \geq 1$, but that doesn't mean that $P_{min} = 1$

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1647286/42969

Comment: Thanks everyone! I think I've found the error. The equality in AG-GM already identifies a unique $\theta = \frac\pi4,$ while the 2nd equality occurs when $\theta = 0$ or $\frac\pi2.$

Comment: You can verify by checking if the terms are equal because that's the condition of A.M = G.M.